ASP.NET MVC : create page with list view in same page
I have some problem with create page with list in the same page, I know this is old question, but all example I sow not working in my case, if someone can help, i put some what I need. I have a page where i insert all my invoices and this invoices have many product, so I try to put all things in the same page. Look bellow
My view model
public class PurchaseVM
{
        public Purchases purchases { get;set; }

        public List<Purchases> purchaseList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }
}

My controller:
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public IActionResult Create(PurchaseVM purchaseVM)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         _unitOfWork.Purchase.Add(purchaseVM.purchases);
         _unitOfWork.Save();
         TempData["success"]= "Product added successfully.";

         //return View(purchaseVM);
         return PartialView("_CreatePartialView", _unitOfWork.Purchase.GetAll());
     }
 }

My partial view:
@model List<Purchases>

@foreach (var purchase in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@purchase.PurchaseId</td>
        <td>@purchase.PurcahseDate</td>
        <td>@purchase.Suppliers.SupplierName</td>
        <td>@purchase.Suppliers.SupplierPhone</td>

        <td>
            <!-- Action buttons -->
        </td>
    </tr>
}


Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see and a problem you haven't described.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.
